# python pandas: warning Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead, why?

Tags: python, pandas, sum

From a particular dataframe I would like to create a dataframe containing the sum of the columns.

```
df['sum'] =  df.sum(axis=1)
```

when excuting that line I get the warning:

```
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
```

checking that link the talk goes on about ways to use loc in multiindex dataframes.
My dataframe is not multinidex.

What is the correct way to assign a column named "sum" with the addition of all the int values of the df?

This would not help to avoid the warning

```
x = df.sum(axis=1).copy()
df['sum'] =  x
```

Comment: The question already has answers, sure, but if you are looking for a quick summary (which that thread does NOT give), here's the quick overview: A slice of a dataframe is when you select part of it. Sometimes when you slice, you're then interacting with a copy of the dataframe, not the original any longer. So trying to set a value and do a slice at the same time can make setting the value not happen, hence the warning. To get around it, do something like `x = result.sum(axis=1)` and then `result['sum'] = x`

Comment: Pardon me, that does not fix your problem. Your df must be defined by slicing a previous DataFrame. Instead, add the `.copy()` to where you defined df originally. For example: `df = df_previous.loc[df_previous["columnA"]==0].copy()` Then you won't get the warning later.